# Fullcalendar v4 - Set only specific parent resource to collapse

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am using timeline view on Fullcalendar v4.  I have 3 parent resources and each comes with number of child resources.  Because only 1 out of 3 parent resource is encouraged to be used, I want to set other 2 parent resources to be collapsed on initial view.

I have found this setting, which sets all the parent resources to collapse.  But it does not allow me to set each parent resource to be expanded or collapsed.
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resourcesInitiallyExpanded

Is there anyway I can reach my goal?

Comment: Short answer, no, unfortunately.

Comment: ok, I gues I have to give up on this. thanx for the answer.

Comment: You could always make a feature request if you'd like to be able to use it in future. There are some instructions on the fullCalendar website about how to do it. I think they sometimes accept code contributions too, so you could maybe even code it yourself and get it accepted into a future release

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your resource structure, this can be accomplished with a combination of [batchRendering](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-batchRendering) and an extension to the Calendar API.

I used a flat resource array structure rather than grouping (resourceAreaColumns/resourceGroupField) so each top level (collapsing) resource has a unique Id (can also be accomplished with nested array structure).

```
resources: [
{ id: 'a', title: 'Room A' },
{ id: 'a1', parentId: 'a',  title: 'Room A1'  },
{ id: 'b', title: 'Room B' },
{ id: 'b1', parentId: 'b',  title: 'Room B1'  },
{ id: 'c', title: 'Room C' },
{ id: 'c1', parentId: 'c',  title: 'Room C1'  }
]
```

Next, I extended the calendar Api with a function that expands a resource by its id using the internal dispatching mechanism.

```
calendar.expandResourceById = function(resourceId, expanded) {
this.dispatch({
    type: 'SET_RESOURCE_ENTITY_EXPANDED',
    id: resourceId,
    isExpanded: expanded,
});
}
```

Lastly, leverage the ability of batch rendering to delay re-render until the last operation.

```
calendar.batchRendering(function() {
   calendar.expandResourceById('c', true);
});
```

**Edit V1**

Thought of another way to accomplish the same, but more dynamically. Setting a custom boolean property ('initiallyExpanded' in this case) to the top level resources extendedProps will allow you to set any resource you want expanded on initial render.

```
 { id: 'c', title: 'Room C', initiallyExpanded: true }
```

Then, change the batchRendering function to get the top level resources, and iterate through the list expanding those with said property set to true.

```
calendar.batchRendering(function() {
calendar.getTopLevelResources().forEach(res => {
  if(res?.extendedProps?.initiallyExpanded){
    calendar.expandResourceById(res.id, true);
  }
})
});
```

Full updated demo available on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Leo-Aslanian/pen/XWywvqW)